# Excel VBA - Set value of multi column combobox based on second column

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a multicolumn combobox
First column is a number ID and second one a string, like this

| ID | STRING |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value 1 |
| 2 | value 2 |

What I want is to set the selected value of the combobox based on the value of the second column

Lets say I click a listbox that contains the string "value 1", then I want to combobox to be selected on that.

Using ComboBox.value does not work because needs to be based on the first column

Appreciate any help

Comment: https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/2045/multi-column-combobox-drop-down-menus-in-forms

Comment: @braX cannot find anything related to that in this article

Comment: You don't see the part at the end where it shows you how to use `Column()`?

Comment: has no use for what I want: it serves only to read a value from a column, lets say textbox.value = CoBo.Column(1).
What I want to do is CoBo.Column(1) = textbox.value (which does not work)

Comment: Have you tried the `.List()` collection?

Comment: does not work for what I want. Are you even testing it yourself?

Comment: Maybe you could use a loop?

Comment: If it's OK with you, maybe you can try to add the cell address when populating the first column of the multi column combobox and hide this first column. Assume that value1 in cell B2, value2 in cell B3 then your combobox first column (which is hidden) has $B$2 and $B$3. Example: user type "value2" in a textbox (or click "value2" item in a listbox), then the code find the address of cell with value "value2" which will be $B$3, then  in the first column of combox select $B$3 value ---> `combobox.value = columns(2).find(textbox/listbox.value).address`

Comment: But it's only if you populate your combox by loop. If you populate it with an array or with a row source, then we can not fill the first column of combox with the cell address. So I think we need to use braX suggestion, loop the combox and check if the combox listindex 1 value is the same with TB/LB value, then select it.

Comment: just realize that you have ID in the first column of combox. So maybe you can try : `combobox.value = columns(2).find(textbox/listbox.value).offset(0,-1).value` without the need to add a first hidden columns (contains cell address) into the combox.